# Query Regarding Group ID Concept

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a specific query regarding the availability of a Group ID concept in RabbitMQ similar to the one offered by Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS). I would greatly appreciate your assistance in providing clarification on this matter.